# floating div box right inside head

Tags: html, css

look's like i have a blackout. As you can see her in the pic i would like to have the box where newsletter is written on the right side of the header. but if im floating it right or left the header is gone, the same if im giving the head the position absolute or relative.

usually i do not have problems with floating but it looks like that i lost during my holidays some stuff.

[preview pic](http://i43.tinypic.com/29yfn6h.jpg)
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ae7b5/)

```
<div class="main">

<div id="header">
    <div class="headcontainer"><h3>Newsletter</h3></div>
</div>
```

```
.main{
    width: 1060px;
    position: relative;
    margin:80px auto;
}

#header{
    width: 1060px;
    margin: 0auto;
    background: #fff;
    clear :both;
    position: relative;
}

.headcontainer {
    /*float:;*/
}
```

Comment: Why cant you just `text-align: right;`. Oh, just looked at the image. I will have a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because when you float there is no `height` in the header anymore. So give the header a height and its fine.

**Note:** The `border` + `width` + `height` is just to show you where it is.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Ae7b5/3/)

**CSS:**

```
#header {
    width:1060px;
    height: 30px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
}
.headcontainer {
    float:right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just setting your content container to `text-align:right;`

That seems to get the desired result for me :)

That would then be:

```
#header{
width:1060px;
margin:0 auto;
background:#fff;
clear:both;
position:relative;
text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the comments at all?